# Faenza / Ubuntu Mono power icon problems

Tags: 11.10, themes, icons, power-cog

Im having problems applying a new icon theme in ubuntu 11.10 specifically with the power icon. Ive installed faenza succesfully, and the gnome tweak tool to change the icons, but the power icon doesnt seem to be updating:

[image: Incorrect power icon]

No matter what i change the icon theme to now, i cant seem to get the power icon to return to the default one, let alone the faenza one. Any suggestions where im going wrong?

Comment: Does this problem remain after restart or logging out? In my experience, the power manager indicator has to be restarted to apply the new icon theme.

Comment: Yea ive tried restarting a couple of times, doesnt seem to make any  difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this problem too.  I prefer the Faenza-Dark variant but has a rubbish battery icon like in your screenshot.  If you used the ppa to install the icons then you should have a Faenza-Ambiance/Radiance theme to choose which fixes it, but as I prefer the -Dark variant I had to make a custom version.  What I did was copied Faenza-Dark to another folder like Faenza-Custom `sudo cp -r /usr/share/icons/Faenza-Dark /usr/share/icons/Faenza-Custom`
Then edit  it.  `sudo nano /usr/share/icons/Faenza-Custom/index.theme` delete everything in it and paste in this

```
[Icon Theme]  
Name=Faenza-Custom  
Inherits=Faenza  
Comment=Icon theme project with tilish style, by Tiheum

Directories=status/22,stock/22  

[status/22]  
Size=22  
Context=Status  
Type=Fixed  

[stock/22]  
Size=22  
Context=stock  
Type=Fixed
```

then use gnome-tweak-tool to choose the Faenza-Custom theme and it will have the fixed battery icon

Comment: duffydack, thanks a lot for the tip, that worked for me, however the notification bubble that comes up once in a while when the battery is discharging, the same old (ugly) icon is still there... anything I can do about that? thanks

Comment: Thanks for this (I prefer the Dark variant too). There's one problem, I think: shouldn't it be "Inherits=Faenza-Dark"?

Comment: Faenza is where most of the variants inherit from.  All I know is, it works.

Comment: I just unplugged mine and never got any bubble.  hmm.  did you make the custom icon folder 755?  `sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/share/icons/Faenza-Custom`

Comment: *edit* just did it again and had the notification, all looks fine.  http://i.imgur.com/dxymI.png

Comment: I just found that on my system if I had the custom set inherit Faenza some of panel icons at the top right become dark, which doesn't mesh so well with the Ambiance theme. If it inherits Faenza-Dark the custom set has lighter icons.

Comment: sorry people, I made a mistake.  I copied the Faenza-Dark folder not the Ambiance folder.  I adjusted the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too using Radiance theme, but I fixed it replazing the folder icons from `/usr/share/Faenza-Radiance/status/22` with `/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/status/22`